# Fusion tables insert via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

Whenever I try to "insert" lines into a fusion table using the non sql method I get the following error: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I am authenticated and can insert using the sql insert statement, but this has low limits for length of insert so I am trying to use a different method.

```
function temp () {
  var tableId = "<table id>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(['hi', 'how', 'are you'].join(','), 
      {type: "octet/stream"});
  ret = FusionTables.Table.importRows(tableId, blob);
  Logger.log([ret,"for id"])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others landing on this question when creating the blob the [documentation for Utilities.newBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte,String)) requires a `Byte[]` and `String`. The working function would be:

```
function temp () {
  var tableId = "<table id>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(['hi', 'how', 'are you'].join(','), 
      'application/octet-stream');
  ret = FusionTables.Table.importRows(tableId, blob);
  Logger.log([ret,"for id"])
}
```

For a tutorial on using FusionTables with Google Apps Script that contains a number of useful helper scripts see [Integrating Google Analytics & Fusion Tables [Tutorial]](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/fusion-tables)